# Mysql field value is truncated when ordered in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysqli

**update** seems to be an issue w/ mysql because it truncates it from the command line too

anyway a db admin at my work figured it out.. see my solution

In PHP (PDO, php_mysql, and php_mysqli all tested) I have a query using group_concat. When it is ordered the data in that field is truncated.

The queries are identical except for that in the second one I have commented out the order by statement. I added the where clause so it would only fetch a few records. Interestingly the data will not be truncated if you select EXACTLY one record with the order by statement as in ID=130... but if you select it as a range it truncates it ID < 131 and ID > 129

The example is using PDO although it doesn't seem to matter what driver i use

**Note: I tried CAST as char(1000) and that doesn't work**

Here is my example code and the output

```
<?php
define('AREA','');
include ("phoenix/includes/config.php");
$config =& PhoenixConfig::get_instance();
$conn=$config->dbh;  //a PDO connection

$truncated="SELECT
  `ac_Export`.`ID` AS 'db-ac_Export-ID',
  `ac_Export`.`RunDate` AS 'db-ac_Export-RunDate',
  `ac_Export`.`Result` AS 'db-ac_Export-Result',
  `ac_Export`.`LogFile` AS 'db-ac_Export-LogFile',
  `ac_Export`.`Type` AS 'db-ac_Export-Type',
  `ac_Export`.`cscart_users_ID` AS 'db-ac_Export-cscart_users_ID',
  `ac_Export`.`cscart_user_name` AS 'db-ac_Export-cscart_user_name',
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    ac_Batch.BatchCode
    ORDER BY ac_Batch.BatchCode SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS 'db-ac_Export-AllIncludedBatches'
FROM
  ac_Export
  LEFT JOIN ac_ExportBatch
    ON ac_Export.ID = ac_ExportBatch.ac_Export_ID 
  LEFT JOIN ac_Batch
    ON ac_ExportBatch.ac_Batch_ID = ac_Batch.ID

    where ac_Export.ID < 131 and ac_Export.ID > 129

GROUP BY ac_Export.ID
ORDER BY `db-ac_Export-RunDate` DESC
LIMIT 0,100 ";

echo "<h3>Truncated</h3>";


    $sql = $truncated;
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        if ($row['db-ac_Export-ID']==130)
        {
            echo $row["db-ac_Export-AllIncludedBatches"];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }



  $sql="SELECT
  `ac_Export`.`ID` AS 'db-ac_Export-ID',
  `ac_Export`.`RunDate` AS 'db-ac_Export-RunDate',
  `ac_Export`.`Result` AS 'db-ac_Export-Result',
  `ac_Export`.`LogFile` AS 'db-ac_Export-LogFile',
  `ac_Export`.`Type` AS 'db-ac_Export-Type',
  `ac_Export`.`cscart_users_ID` AS 'db-ac_Export-cscart_users_ID',
  `ac_Export`.`cscart_user_name` AS 'db-ac_Export-cscart_user_name',
  CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(
    ac_Batch.BatchCode
    ORDER BY ac_Batch.BatchCode SEPARATOR ', '
  ) AS CHAR(1000)) AS 'db-ac_Export-AllIncludedBatches'
FROM
  ac_Export
  LEFT JOIN ac_ExportBatch
    ON ac_Export.ID = ac_ExportBatch.ac_Export_ID
  LEFT JOIN ac_Batch
    ON ac_ExportBatch.ac_Batch_ID = ac_Batch.ID
WHERE ac_Export.ID < 131 and ac_Export.ID > 129
GROUP BY ac_Export.ID
/*ORDER BY `db-ac_Export-RunDate` DESC */
LIMIT 0, 100 ";
echo "<h3>Not Truncated</h3>";
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo $row["db-ac_Export-AllIncludedBatches"];
    }

?>
```

Output example:

> Truncated
>
> G2013050301, G2013050702, G2013052901, G2013053103,
>   G2013060500, P2013050103, P2013050201, P2013050301, P2013050702,
>   P2013050802, P2013050901, P2013051101, P2013051200, P2013051301,
>   P2013051401, P2013051501, P2013051601, P2013051701, P2013052102,
>   P2013052201, P2013052301, P2013052600, P2013052700, P2013052801,
>   P2013052901, P2013053001, P20
>
> Not Truncated
>
> G2013050301, G2013050702,
>   G2013052901, G2013053103, G2013060500, P2013050103, P2013050201,
>   P2013050301, P2013050702, P2013050802, P2013050901, P2013051101,
>   P2013051200, P2013051301, P2013051401, P2013051501, P2013051601,
>   P2013051701, P2013052102, P2013052201, P2013052301, P2013052600,
>   P2013052700, P2013052801, P2013052901, P2013053001, P2013053102,
>   P2013060500

Comment: The queries are identical.. ORLY? and `AS CHAR(1000))`?

Comment: agreed, you should add AS CHAR(1000)) to your first query.

Comment: Thanks for the char suggetion.. I tried that already and it didn't work.  the queries are not identical. The second query has the order by statement commented out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a DB admin at my work figured out that this setting will fix the issue

SET group_concat_max_len=4096;

This really doesn't explain for me why ordering the field would impact it, but it does seem to work now.

you can set

```
group_concat_max_len=<size you want>M
```

in your

my.cnf / my.ini